# Javascript to convert html to bbcode, for images with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

I have a image gallery made in php. I have made a little php script that generates a code with my latest uploaded pictures, a list of thumbnails that have a structure like this (I can change the structure if needed):

```
<div class="thumbs">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="http://example.com/picture1.php" class="bbcode" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/99x99" alt="http://example.com/picture2.php" class="bbcode" />
</div>

<textarea class="message" rows="10" cols="60">

</textarea>
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/xwhg3nch/

I need a javascript (can be based on any JS library) that when I click a picture to create a BBCODE image with link for it in my textarea, example:

```
[url=http://example.com/picture1.php][img]http://placehold.it/100x100[/img][/url]
[url=http://example.com/picture2.php][img]http://placehold.it/99x99[/img][/url]
```

and put a small border around the picture (for me to see that I already clicked that picture).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there using jquery you can use an on click function

```
$('body').on('click', 'img.bbcode', function() {
var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
$('.message').append('[url=' + imgsrc + '][img]' + imgsrc + '[/img][/url]');
$(this).css('border', '1px solid #000');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x5sgycuk/1/

hope that helps

Comment: AceWebDesign i just made it myself https://jsfiddle.net/xwhg3nch/ after reading some docs and some examples and the code is very similar to yours, so i will consider your response as the answer. I never thought is so simple (i only new php and html language), that why I asked help.

Comment: I'm thinking to add some protection to not generate the code twice for an image that has been allready clicked. I must probably use .attr or .html to check if that image have a border? and if has no border to insert the bbcode in textarea. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in Pure JS:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("bbcode");
var textArea = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0];
var length = imgs.length;

for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    var element = imgs[i];

  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var imgSrc = element.src;
    textArea.value += "[url=" + imgSrc + "][img]" + imgSrc + "[/img][/url]";
  });
}
```